# How can i get gcc profile guided optimizations to stop writing files after being 'optimized'?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compilation, gcov

I'm doing this in a makefile and it results on the first run creating the .gcda files in that dir; but as soon as i do the second, if find that the executable is almost as slow (and this is surely related), is still writing *new* files to the dir after compiled. From my understanding this shouldn't occur. Removing `-fprofile-arcs` (or `-lgcov` for that matter) makes the second compile complain about missing symbols. What amd i missing? I `make clean` in between both of these executions btw.

I also tried some variations besides `-lgcov`but i reached this one from reading the manual and realizing `-fprofile-use` opens a lot of optimizations, including `-fprofile-arcs` and no easy alternative i tried was working.

```
PROFILE_DIR=/tmp/pgo/${PN}
ifeq ($(wildcard $(PROFILE_DIR)),)
all:
  CXXFLAGS += -O3 -march=native -fprofile-generate=${PROFILE_DIR} -fprofile-correction
  CFLAGS   += -O3 -march=native -fprofile-generate=${PROFILE_DIR} -fprofile-correction
  LDFLAGS  += -fprofile-arcs
  $(info profile-sampling build)
else
all:
  CXXFLAGS += -O3 -march=native -fprofile-use=${PROFILE_DIR} -fprofile-correction
  CFLAGS   += -O3 -march=native -fprofile-use=${PROFILE_DIR} -fprofile-correction
  LDFLAGS  += -fprofile-arcs
  $(info profile-guided build)
endif
```

gcc version is `gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008`

edit: the final LDFLAGS of the case with the files already is : `-lpthread -ldl -lrt -fPIC -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--version-script=link.T -fprofile-arcs`

If i'm not mistaken,`-Wl,--no-undefined` is sabotaging not linking `gcov` or not using `-fprofile-arcs` because the symbols for `gcov` are somewhere in the files used even if they're no longer important and that option explicitly fails the compile on all missing symbols. So the solution might be omitting `-fprofile-arcs` in the second compile and (somehow) allowing just this single library `gcov` to have uninitialized symbols. I don't know how to try the second.

edit 2: unfortunately, no, it crashes at runtime without that flag and without the linking to -gcov (direct or indirect). So *something* in the .gcda files is forcing -lgcov and that forces the resulting executable to start writing .gcda files, but if you try to remove the -lgcov you either get a failed build or a crash at runtime. I don't understand how this is supposed to work, or why those files are not just a compile time artifact....

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by 'make clean' not removing all created .o files but a outdated partial hardcoded list. The second compilation 'reused' some .o files from the first (instrumented) compilation, and thus required the -lgcov LDFLAG which naturally started the second compilation to profile again.